# Python: dynamically adding classes to QtWidgets.QMainWindow() instance?

Tags: python, subclass, qt-designer, qtwidgets

I have many QtDesigner py files (version 5.11).  I want to include the classes of the QtDesigner py files in a main class.  Manually, I would do this for the first subclass, mainMenu.py

```
menu = QtWidgets.QMainWindow() 

menu.Ui_mainMenu = mainMenu.Ui_mainMenu
menu.QtCore = mainMenu.QtCore
menu.QtGui = mainMenu.QtGui
menu.QtWidgets = mainMenu.QtWidgets
```

Then, I'd have to take the next QtDesigner-generated py file and add its Ui_nextMenu, etc.  I suppose that there must be an automated way to populate the menu class with all the Ui_* classes from the files.  Any help, please.

Comment: Why do you have Qt modules in `mainMenu`?

Comment: Hi.  I am writing a program with class Example(QMainWindow, menu), where menu contains all the subclasses.  Each subclass contains a Qt module with a different GUI.  The program will swap one GUI for another based on command and a hierarchy for selection.